# Ansible- changing directory for all tasks

Tags: ansible

I have a script that I want to write as a playbook.

first I should go to my specific directory and then run some tsm commands for backup and cleanup.

I tried to change directory which works fine. but the tasks after that("list files") is running in my home directory.
How can I change the working directory for all tasks?
Thanks for your help!

```yaml
- name: "Change Directory"
  win_shell: cd /d E:\mydirectory
  args:
    executable: cmd

- name: list files
  win_shell: dir
  args:
    executable: cmd
  register: myfiles
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each task is independent, so you have to change the working directory on each `win_shell` invocation. One way to do this is to use [`module_defaults`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html) on a block:

```yaml
- module_defaults:
    win_shell:
      executable: cmd
      chdir: 'E:\mydirectory'
  block:
    - name: list files
      win_shell: dir
      register: myfiles
```